What does "this thing" refer to?
In Vice (2018), George W. Bush and Dick Cheney walk side by side at the ranch:

GEORGE W. BUSH: Karl Rove wanted me to buy this ranch,
distance myself from my years at Yale and Harvard,
make me more of a man of the people for the election.
Dick Cheney: Mmm. Smart.

They both take a seat:

GEORGE W. BUSH: So we gonna do this thing or what? I mean, is this happening?
Dick Cheney: We, uh, have found some very interesting candidates.
Um, if we could schedule a three-hour window to get through...
GEORGE W. BUSH: I meant you. I want you to be my VP.

What does "this thing" refer to?

https://youtu.be/EkqrI3IibYI?si=MtlPPuSwKJaM-UWQ   You might enjoy.

The fact that Cheney himself misunderstood slightly should suggest that it wasn't terribly clear. Cheney took "this thing" to be "help me select a vice presidential candidate," and Bush meant it as "run on a ticket together."

@TimR Question is about English language not Youtube clip.

@M.KAng  The Youtube video  I linked to (a comedy sketch) imitates Bush's manner of speaking, the way he uses words, and would shed some light on "this thing.  If you're lying on an operating table, and slipping into unconcsciousness, and you hear the surgeon say to the team, "So, we gonna do this thing?"  you should try to wake up and get off the table and find another surgeon.

I meant you. I want you to be my VP. suggests that this thing refers to the proposed president/ vice-president partnership.

So we gonna do this [president/ vice-president partnership] or what?

